# Странное поведение у len() и у np.size()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Есть функции:

```
def split_data_lambda(X, y, t):
    predicate = X < t
    xL, yL = map(lambda x: np.take(x, np.where(predicate)), (X, y))
    xR, yR = map(lambda x: np.take(x, np.where(~predicate)), (X, y))
    return xL, yL, xR, yR

def regression_var_criterion_lambda(X, y, t):
    xL, yL, xR, yR = split_data_lambda(X, y, t)
    return np.var(y) - np.size(yL) / float(np.size(y)) * np.var(yL) - np.size(yR) / float(np.size(y)) * np.var(yR)
```

Если я вычисляю строку в `regression_var_criterion_lambda`:

```
return np.var(y) - np.size(yL) / float(np.size(y)) * np.var(yL) - np.size(yR) / float(np.size(y)) * np.var(yR)
```

то получаю верный ответ. Строю график:

```
threshold = np.arange(-1.9, 1.9, 0.01)
total = [regression_var_criterion_lambda(X, y, t) for t in threshold]
plt.plot(linspace, total, '-');
```

[image: Верный график]

Если я вычисляю строку в `regression_var_criterion_lambda` с заменой на `len()`:

```
return np.var(y) - len(yL) / float(len(y)) * np.var(yL) - len(yR) / float(len(y)) * np.var(yR)
```

то получаю неверный график:

[image: Неверный график]

Подскажите причины

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[np.size()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html) возвращает число элементов в матрице, т.е. произведение размерностей: `np.product(arr.shape)`, тогда как `len()` возвращает длину первой размерности.

Пример:

```
In [193]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)

In [194]: a.shape
Out[194]: (4, 3)

In [195]: np.size(a)
Out[195]: 12

In [196]: len(a)
Out[196]: 4

In [197]: len(a) == a.shape[0]
Out[197]: True
```

Comment: Понял, да... Спасибо. Нужно было вчера спать идти. А не полуночничать.